# Using XPATH to retrieve values from repeating XML nodes

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I am new to XML parsing and Java. I am trying to parse an xml using XPATH. The XML looks like this

```
<Root>
 <AL1>
  <AL1.1>1</AL1.1>
  <AL1.2>1</AL1.2>
  <AL1.3>
    <CX1.1>Bala</CX1.1>
  </AL1.1>
<AL1>
<AL1>
  <AL1.1>2</AL1.1>
  <AL1.2>1</AL1.2>
  <AL1.3>
    <CX1.1>Bala1</CX1.1>
  </AL1.1>
<AL1>
<AL1>
  <AL1.1>3</AL1.1>
  <AL1.2>1</AL1.2>
  <AL1.3>
    <CX1.1>Bala2</CX1.1>
  </AL1.1>
<AL1>
</Root>
```

I framed the XPATH like this for getting CX1.1 value /AL1/AL1.3/CX1.1/text(). So far I am able to get only the first occurrence if CX1.1.

```
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("/AL1/AL1.3/CX1.1/text()");
result = (String) expr.evaluate(doc.XPathConstants.STRING);
```

Could you guys please let me know of a way to get all the different values of CX1.1 in a List using XPATH. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the XML that you have provided is not well-formed, but once well-formed, I would do the following:

```
  String expression = "//AL1/AL1.3/CX1.1/text()";

        NodeList list = (NodeList) xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);

        List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++) {
            strings.add(list.item(i).toString());
        }
```

Which is to save the result of the xpath query in a `NodeList` and then iterate over it to save each value in a `List<String>` with a loop.

Answer (score 0):

First, fix your XML to be well-formed:

- The `AL1.3` start tags should not be closed with `AL1.1` end tags, and
- your `AL1` start tags should be closed with `AL1` end tags, not start tags.

**Corrected XML:**

```
<Root>
  <AL1>
    <AL1.1>1</AL1.1>
    <AL1.2>1</AL1.2>
    <AL1.3>
      <CX1.1>Bala</CX1.1>
    </AL1.3>
  </AL1>
  <AL1>
    <AL1.1>2</AL1.1>
    <AL1.2>1</AL1.2>
    <AL1.3>
      <CX1.1>Bala1</CX1.1>
    </AL1.3>
  </AL1>
  <AL1>
    <AL1.1>3</AL1.1>
    <AL1.2>1</AL1.2>
    <AL1.3>
      <CX1.1>Bala2</CX1.1>
    </AL1.3>
  </AL1>
</Root>
```

**Corrected XPath**

Then fix your XPath to take into account the `Root` element,

```
/Root/AL1/AL1.3/CX1.1/text()
```

or disregard the heritage of `CX1.1` elements altogether:

```
//CX1.1/text()
```

**Corrected Java**

Finally, see Mary Grass's concurrent answer (+1) on how to fix your Java code so that the the given type is a `XPathConstants.NODESET`, not `XPathConstants.STRING`.